# DLL doesn't store string C#

Tags: c#

I have an application that can be launched from the explorer context menu for a Windows drive. When you click the menu item the drive letter is passed to the new instance. I want to make sure that any old instance is closed.

I also want to make sure that the last drive that was selected is persisted, so that when I start the application again from the start-menu, it will remember the drive I originally selected.

It would be best if the already running application would receive an event so that it can update without having to kill and restart.

---

I tried the following, but that doesn't seem to be working:

This is my Class library method(it is just a line that define a variable so just i have a DLL that there a variable in it and no more)

```
 namespace Dispatch
 {
     public class cls_get_drive_letter
     {
         public static string drive_letter;
     }
 }
```

This is my loading form code: (Here i will fill the DLL's variable)

```
 private void Frm_loading_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Dispatch.cls_get_drive_letter.drive_letter = "XXX";
     Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
     if (Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName, currentProcess.MachineName).Length >1)
     {
        currentProcess.Kill();
     }
 }
```

So when i run this for first time the "XXX" will be stored in DLL but when the current instance of application is running and i am going to run next instance of it the application will be closed because of this code:

```
 Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 if (Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName, currentProcess.MachineName).Length >1)
 {
     currentProcess.Kill();
 }
```

So when closing code occurs with this code the new "XXX" will not stored in DLL and the last string will be in dll.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stored in DLL'?

Comment: What is exactly what you're trying to accomplish? Not from the perspective of storing a string in a static variable, but at the functional level. What I understand is, you have a running process, when your application is started, you need to store some state, then kill the running process? Why?

Answer (score 4):

All variables, in this case a static field, will only remain the same for the running instance of your application.
When the application is started again the field is empty

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with it. This applies to all variables unless they are persisted to another storage location.

Comment: @Ash - just explaining what static does and doesn't

Comment: @JeroenMoonen, my point is your answer reads, `A static field will` when it should be `All variables will`. Its sounds like you are implying that this is happening because it is marked as `static` which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

A static variable is not stored 'inside a dll' but is stored inside the memory of the application that loads the dll. When a second instance of the application starts, it will have its own memory space and it will have its own version of the string variable. The variable is also not kept between instances, so as soon as you start a new instance it will have its own, empty string variable.

When the application is stopped, the memory for that instance is released and the variable is 'forgotten'.

If you want to share state between applications, there are all kinds of solutions, one could be the System.Configuration.Settings API, a file somewhere, a memory mapped file shared between multiple processes, a Named Pipe, a Kernel Semaphore. Options aplenty.

Until we understand exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish with this shared state, we can't provide you with a better alternative than the explanation that what you're doing right now, will not work do to the way static variables work.

---

**Update based on new information:**

You can store your currently selected drive in a [Settings file for your project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a65txexh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can add such file from the project properties in Visual Studio. There's a tab called settings. Create a new setting for "Selected Drive" and make it a User setting (that way you can update it without Admin rights).

To communicate a new drive letter to your already running application, you have a number of options.

1. For one, you could check whether your executable is already running (like you're doing now) and in that case update the settings file and exit the new instance. Your already running instance could periodically refresh the settings to pick up new values.
2. When your application starts, you can open a named pipe on your machine on which you listen for drive changes. When the 2nd instance starts, it can detect that the pipe is already there, write the new drive to the pipe and close. The already running application can pick up this message and change its configuration.
3. You can send a WindowMessage to the other application
4. You can host a simple WCF service to receive the notification
5. You can write the new drive letter to a file stored in a known location and have the other instance use a FileSystemWatcher to detect the changes to that file.
6. As I said the possibilities are endless.

If I were you I'd first make sure that the value is persisted between relaunches by implementing the Settings file in your application. Then investigate the options I described above, do some experimentation and then ask new questions when you cannot figure out how to make it work.

Comment: My work is this that i added my application name to windows right click (When right click on drives).So each time it will send the drive name to my C# application

Comment: And you want your application to relaunch for that specific drive? Or do you want your running application to pick up the new drive and keep running?

Comment: As you know each time application will re-lunch because when i click on my APPLICATION NAME on windows right click the windows will re-lunch it. but if it is possible to lunch once it is to much better

Comment: Thanks to all. I prefer to use .net settings.